# Не могу сделать из двух массивов одни, без одинаковых элементов

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Рабочая html</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
    </head>
<body>

<script>
var arr1 = [1, 2];
var arr2 = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(getDiff(arr1, arr2));

function getDiff(arr1Elem, arr2Elem) {
    var len1 = arr1Elem.length;
    var len2 = arr2Elem.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < len1; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < len2; j++) {
            if (arr1Elem[i] == arr2Elem[j]) {
                arr2Elem.splice(j, 1);
            };
        };
    };
    var arr = arr1Elem.concat(arr2Elem);
    return arr;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Нужна функция, которая параметром будет принимать два массива и возвращать массив элементов, которые не присутствуют одновременно в обоих массивах.

У меня получается только удалить одинаковые элементы из одного массива а из другого массива нет.
P.S. Учу java script.

Comment: @AlexKrass "не присутствуют одновременно в обоих массивах"

Comment: @AlexKrass теперь ок

Comment: А можете код написать, а то я не понимаю что значит "!(elem in newArray)"

Comment: @КамранРаджабов можно проверить вхождение элемента так: `if( !newArr.includes(elem) && !arr2Elem.includes(elem)) newArr.push(elem);`. Где elem - это значение из первого массива arr1Elem, а newArr новый массив внутри функции (`var newArr = []`). Можно конечно и сразу полный код, но вы же учитесь и я думаю хотите научиться.

Comment: мне нужно чтобы было по простому, a тут  не понятно. "!(elem in newArray)" и  !newArr.includes(elem) не изучал,  прогуглил понял что значит но это не то

Comment: @КамранРаджабов [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexof) вы изучали? Поскольку `splice` и `concat` тоже относятся к функциям работы с массивами, поэтому по идее должны были.

Comment: @AlexKrass да изучал

Comment: @КамранРаджабов можете заменить на него `if( newArr.indexOf(elem) == -1 && arr2Elem.indexOf(elem) == -1) newArr.push(elem);` Просто `includes` его аналогия. Про `in` можете забыть, я проверил сейчас, он не работает с массивом из целых чисел.

Comment: @AlexKrass я по этому прошу код, потому что, в голове все работает а когда код пишешь  уже нет

Comment: @КамранРаджабов ладно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var b = [3, 4, 5, 6];

function getDiff(arr1Elem, arr2Elem) {
    var len1 = arr1Elem.length;
    var len2 = arr2Elem.length;
    var newArr = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < len1; i++) {
        var elem = arr1Elem[i];
        if(newArr.indexOf(elem) == -1 && arr2Elem.indexOf(elem) == -1) 
            newArr.push(elem);
    };
    
    for (var i = 0; i < len2; i++) {
        var elem = arr2Elem[i];
        if(newArr.indexOf(elem) == -1 && arr1Elem.indexOf(elem) == -1) 
            newArr.push(elem);
    };
    
    return newArr;
}

console.log(getDiff(a, b));
```

Comment: вот теперь я точно понял, спасибо))